# C# Static Readonly log4net logger, any way to change logger in Unit Test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, log4net, moq

My class has this line:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Prim));
```

When I go to unit test, I can't inject a moq logger into this interface so I could count log calls.

Is there a way to do this?  Log4net recommends static readonly pattern for loggers.  What's best way to handle it?

Comment: Log4net supports custom Appenders so you should be able to know about all logging calls this way (similar for most logging frameworks - including default .Net one with `Trace`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While log4net recommends this pattern, nothing prevents you from instantiating the logger outside the class, and inject it. Most of the IoCs can be configured to inject one and the same instance. That way, for your unit tests you can inject a mock.

I would recommend a wrapper around LogManager.GetLogger, which returns always one and the same logger instance per type:

```
namespace StackOverflowExample.Moq
{
    public interface ILogCreator
    {
        ILog GetTypeLogger<T>() where T : class;
    }

    public class LogCreator : ILogCreator
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<Type, ILog> loggers = new Dictionary<Type, ILog>();
        private static readonly object lockObject;

        public ILog GetTypeLogger<T>() where T : class
        {
            var loggerType = typeof (T);
            if (loggers.ContainsKey(loggerType))
            {
                return loggers[typeof (T)];
            }

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (loggers.ContainsKey(loggerType))
                {
                    return loggers[typeof(T)];
                }
                var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerType);
                loggers[loggerType] = logger;
                return logger;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClassWithLogger
    {
        private readonly ILog logger;
        public ClassWithLogger(ILogCreator logCreator)
        {
            logger = logCreator.GetTypeLogger<ClassWithLogger>();
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            logger.Debug("called");
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class Log4Net
    {
        [Test]
        public void DoSomething_should_write_in_debug_logger()
        {
            //arrange
            var logger = new Mock<ILog>();
            var loggerCreator = Mock.Of<ILogCreator>(
                c =>
                c.GetTypeLogger<ClassWithLogger>() == logger.Object);

            var sut = new ClassWithLogger(loggerCreator);

            //act
            sut.DoSomething();

            //assert
            logger.Verify(l=>l.Debug("called"), Times.Once());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, I suspect there's no real alternative if using readonly static.  What are consequences of removing readonly or static?

Comment: readonly is not removed, but even if it is, there is no consequences. For the static, also there is no consequence, as far as a singleton logger is used, and it will based on the above implementation. You will get negligible performance hit for the factory work on each ClassWithLogger creation, but its very very small. So unless you are writing a device driver, or you are creating gazzilion instances of ClassWithLogger, there is no real drawback. The expensive part is the actual logger creation, and it is mitigated by the singleton.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MemoryAppender` instead a mocked logger. By this approach, you can configure log4net to collect the log events in memory and get them by `GetEvents()` to verify.

I found the these useful examples:

- https://gist.github.com/plaurin/3563082#file-trycache-cs
- http://jake.ginnivan.net/verifying-logged-messages-with-log4net/

Here is the first:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    this.memoryAppender = new MemoryAppender();
    BasicConfigurator.Configure(this.memoryAppender);

    ...
}

[Test]
public void TestSomething()
{
    ...

    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(
        this.memoryAppender.GetEvents().Any(le => le.Level == Level.Error),
        "Did not expect any error messages in the logs");
}
```

And the more detailed:

```
public static class Log4NetTestHelper
{
    public static string[] RecordLog(Action action)
    {
        if (!LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
            BasicConfigurator.Configure();
        var logMessages = new List<string>();
        var root = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
        var attachable = root as IAppenderAttachable;

        var appender = new MemoryAppender();
        if (attachable != null)
            attachable.AddAppender(appender);

        try
        {           
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            var loggingEvents = appender.GetEvents();
            foreach (var loggingEvent in loggingEvents)
            {
                var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                loggingEvent.WriteRenderedMessage(stringWriter);
                logMessages.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1} | {2}", loggingEvent.Level.DisplayName, loggingEvent.LoggerName, stringWriter.ToString()));
            }
            if (attachable != null)
                attachable.RemoveAppender(appender);
        }

        return logMessages.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take the `readonly` away, the Logger will work as well as a usual interface object.

See the following simple example being tested:

```
using System;
using log4net;

namespace StackOverflowExample.Moq
{
    public class ClassWithLogger
    {
        private static ILog _log;
        //private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Prim));

    public ClassWithLogger(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

        public void DoSomething(object para = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if(para != null)
                {
                    _log.Debug("called");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Fatal("Exception raised!", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unit Test Code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_DoSomething_logger()
{
    //arrange
    var mockLog = new Mock<log4net.ILog>();
    var classWithLogger = new ClassWithLogger(mockLog.Object);
    mockLog.Setup(m => m.Debug(It.IsAny<string>()));
    mockLog.Setup(m => m.Fatal(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Exception>()));

    //act1
    classWithLogger.DoSomething(new object());

    //assert1
    mockLog.Verify(l => l.Debug("called"), Times.Once());

    //act2
    classWithLogger.DoSomething();

    //assert2
    mockLog.Verify(x => x.Fatal("Exception raised!", It.IsAny<Exception>()));
}
```

And main program call:

```
public void MainProgramCall()
{
    //......
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    var classWithLogger = new ClassWithLogger(log);

    classWithLogger.DoSomething(new object());

    //......

    classWithLogger.DoSomething();

    //......
}
```

Comment: I also came to an idea, that it's better to have constructor-injected loggers. In case one uses `UnityContainer` for DI, it's possible to make the container resolve `ILog` parameters automatically, thus avoiding a lot of boilerplate - see e.g. my [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityLog4NetResolver).